# How can I "undo" a commit pushed to remote Bonobo Git Server?

Tags: git, bonobo

I accidentely pushed the wrong changes to the Git Bonobo Server. Can my commits be undone to where my commits are simply 'deleted'?

Answer (score 0):

Forcing-pushing is potentially dangerous, as it can result in the permanent destruction of commits.  If you are not the sole contributor to the remote repository, then there is a chance you may obliterate someone else's changes.  Even if you *are* the sole contributor to the remote repo, you should still only force-push when there are no alternatives and you are absolutely sure you won't destroy anything.  If anyone else has pushed commits to the remote repository after your initial errant commit, then those commits will be lost forever if you force-push a hard reset.

To safely undo a commit that you've already pushed to the remote repository, you should instead [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commit in question and then push the reversion to the remote repository like so:

```
git revert [commit hash]
git push origin [branch]
```

This way, both the errant commit and the reversion of the errant commit will be visible in the history, and there is no risk of permanently losing any other changes in the remote repository.

Comment: It would be nice if people would leave a comment to explain their downvote.